# Runaway argument for simple newcommand

Tags: errors

I have this macro:

```
\newcommand\myvspace[1][]{
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#1} {
    \hfill \break
  }
}
```

I just want to create some whitespace, so I use it like this:

```
foo
\myvspace{3}
bar
```

However I get this error.

```
Runaway argument?
ndefined\let \pgffor@dotsend =\pgffor@dotsvalue \pgffor@dots@value@process \ETC
.
! Paragraph ended before \pgffor@@dotscharcheck was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
l.120
```

Not sure how to go about debugging this yet, this is my first macro so far :). Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `\myvspace[3]`?  **Edit:** Or rather, `\newcommand{\myvspace}[3]{...}`?

Comment: My apologies, late hour!  I actually meant “Shouldn’t it be `\newcommand{\myvspace}[1]{<your definition>}`?

Comment: Can you please make your code snippet compilable?

Comment: However, this looks like an “X-Y question”.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: this (even with the error fixed) is a very strange command, are you sure you want a sequence of `\hfill` and `\break`, especially a sequence ending in `\break`??? Why not `\vspace{3\baselineskip}` if you want to add three lines worth of space (although explicit space is uusally best avoided of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a macro that contains one optional argument that defaults to empty. The default is given in the second pair of braces.

It's not entirely clear what you intended behavior is, but this at least fixes your error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand\myvspace[1]{%
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#1} {%
    \hfill \break
  }%
}
\begin{document}

foo
\myvspace{3}
bar
\end{document}
```

I can't help but think you should be using `\vspace` or `\vspace*` or `\\`.

Maybe something like

```
\newcommand*\myvspace[1]{%
  \\[#1\baselineskip]%
}
```

But the optional argument is for additional space so you'd need to use `\myvspace{2}` to achieve the effect yours has. (Alternatively, you could do some math and subtract one.)